# Use a parameter attribute as a default value for another parameter?

Tags: python, django

Is there way in python to set the default value of a parameter to a property of another parameter?

eg

I currently have a function in django which I would like to do

```
def supplier_default_product(region, supplier=region.default_supplier.id):
    default_product_instance = Product.objects.get(name=default_product, supplier=supplier)
    ....
```

so that I can call it with either no supplier where it just uses the regions default supplier:

```
supplier_default_product(region)
```

or with a specified supplier:

```
supplier_default_product(region, supplier)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `None` as the default argument and then check in the body of the function for `None`.

```
def supplier_default_product(region, supplier=None):
    if supplier is None:
        supplier = region.default_supplier.id
    default_product_instance = Product.objects.get(name=default_product, supplier=supplier)
```

You can't reference an attribute of another argument, because the default argument values are set at define time, which only happens once.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why it doesn't work too.

Comment: @Yunti No problem. Glad I could help!